# Program parallelisation with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, parallel-processing, pyspark

I am a bit new to PySpark and I am looking how to parallelize a simple program with PySpark. I did not find a Spark transformation that can do this treatment properly.

The treatment I want to do consists somehow in filtering some numeric values of a very large ordered vector / list. In the resulting vector the difference between all 2 consecutive values should be >= X (X is given). The first value of the initial vector should be kept as well.

Eg. v = (1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11), X = 3 then the result is v'=(1, 4, 7, 11).

The program is very simple to implement in 'classical' Python, but the need is to get the result very quickly using Spark parallelisation.

```
##### myDF = data from database
last_retained_value = 0 ### all values in myDF are positive
for value in myDF.collect():
    current_value = value
    if (current_value - last_retained_value >= X): ### X is fixed
        last_retained_value = current_value
        result.append(str(current_value)) ### result is a list which contains final result**
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you post the Python code ?

Comment: Done!! Thanks again.

Comment: Do you require exactly the same result as sequential program?

Comment: Yes indeed. Ideally yes.

Answer (score 0):

Sequential solution you have does not look parallelizable, because fate of every element depends on a complete history (removing a single item can affect all items located after it).

It is easy to get **an approximation** of your sequential code by pruning partitions first:

```
d = 3

rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11], 4)

def prune(xs, d=3):
    prev = None
    for x in xs: 
        if prev is None or abs(x - prev) >= d:
            prev = x
            yield x

pruned = rdd.mapPartitions(prune)
```

and then sweep once again

```
borders = pruned.mapPartitions(lambda xs: [max(xs)]).collect()

pruned.filter(lambda x: any(b < x < b + 3 for b in borders)).collect()
# [3, 8]
```

but as you can see this approach is less conservative and doesn't return the same results as sequential solution.

With larger partitions, and random distributed differences between max(p) and min(p + 1) where p is partition, this should converge to similar output on average, but without any guarantees.

If you want to apply it this by group you can just `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` and apply local logic for each partition.

Comment: I see, and this was my fear. Is it at least possible to do some parallelisation if in myDF I have another column which defines groups of values. Eg. ((1,1), (1, 3), (1,4), (1,7), (1,8), (1,11), (2,7), (2,20), ...). Each group can be treated separatly. Thanks.

Comment: user8371915 please what about distribution of different groups on different nodes and doing parallel treatment of groups (with sequential treatment inside each node)?